# worksheet_change save in xlsx

Tags: excel, xlsx, xlsm, vba

Does the excel file have to be xlsm for the worksheet_change event to work, or can this be done in xlsx. I fear it's only xlsm.
Although it seems like a small thing, asking some co-workers to select 'enable macros' seems to be too much to ask

Comment: It has to be an xlsm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-au/library/aa338205.aspx#office2007aboutnewfileformat_introduction

> Macro-Enabled Files vs. Macro-Free Files
>
> Default 2007 Microsoft Office system documents saved in Office XML
>   Formats are intended to be macro-free files, and therefore cannot
>   contain code. This behavior ensures that malicious code, residing in a
>   default document, can never be executed unexpectedly. While 2007
>   Microsoft Office system documents can still contain and use macros,
>   the user or developer must save these documents as a macro-enabled
>   document type.

Basically the idea of xlsx vs xlsm is that user can tell straight away if there is code in a worbook or not, so if you want to put code in your workbook you must save it as xlsm.